# Extra some properties from a javascript object and pass those to a function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I am looking for a function or set of functions to perform a job through [ramda](http://ramdajs.com/). Here is the ask:-

I have an object and i want to pass it through "pipe" function, extract few parameters from that object and pass the values of those parameters to a function.

For e.g.

```
import {pipe} from 'ramda'
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4
}

const sum = (val1, val2) => val1 + val2

pipe(<extract a,b from obj> and pass it to sum function) ??
```

Any kind of help is really appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trouble with trying to use `pipe` for this is that it (like `compose`) only passes a single argument to anything but the first function called.  You can get around this by using [`apply`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#apply), making your function accept a the parameters in a single array, and using [`props`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#props) to extract that array:

```
pipe(props(['a', 'b']), apply(sum))(obj); //=> 3
```

An alternative is to use the somewhat Ramda-specific [`converge`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#converge) function:

```
converge(sum, [prop('a'), prop('b')])(obj) //=> 3
```

But perhaps better than that  would be a more standard [`lift`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#lift) one:

```
lift(sum)(prop('a'), prop('b'))(obj); //=> 3
```

You can see this all in the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.23.0#?const%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20a%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20b%3A%202%2C%0A%20%20c%3A%203%2C%0A%20%20d%3A%204%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20sum2%20%3D%20%28val1%2C%20val2%29%20%3D%3E%20val1%20%2B%20val2%0A%0Aconsole.log%28pipe%28props%28%5B%27a%27%2C%20%27b%27%5D%29%2C%20apply%28sum2%29%29%28obj%29%29%0A%0Aconsole.log%28converge%28sum2%2C%20%5Bprop%28%27a%27%29%2C%20prop%28%27b%27%29%5D%29%28obj%29%29%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log%28lift%28sum2%29%28prop%28%27a%27%29%2C%20prop%28%27b%27%29%29%28obj%29%29%3B%0A%0A)**.

Comment: This really helped.